# Flutter Hot Reload is not working with Emulator. How to remove Dev Tool?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, android-emulator, flutter-layout

I think I accidentally changed something in my Flutter project. Therefore, when I run the emulator in the project, it opens very slowly and debbuging takes a long time. Even if the project is loaded, when you make changes in the code later, this change is not reflected on the emulator.

Let me briefly explain my problems as follows;

1. I accidentally activated something called Flutter Dev Tool. How do I
   remove it ?
2. Hot Reload not working on emulator.

Comment: I think you might be running flutter in release mode.

Comment: How can I fix this?